# How to host a VM image in Azure pipeline to run the tasks instead of using self hosted agent?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-vm

I have a requirement where I need to host the VM image in Azure pipeline and run the testing with the tools added in the VM image and delete the VM. The main aim is to avoid the cost of permanent VM(Self agent) and create a VM at run time and use it.  Currently, I have taken snapshot of a VM image. But, I did not have enough references to host that VM image in the azure pipeline run time.

In this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/host-build-agent/2-choose-a-build-agent, it explains three types of self hosting. Refer the **How do you set up a private build agent?** topic. I need help in using the third type of self hosted deployment.

Comment: This will be quite a convolluted process. You'd need to create a VM from the Azure Pipleines agent, then run scripts on that VM (from the Azure Pipelines agent) to connect that VM to DevOps. Then you need to somehow handoff your process to the next build step. Anther options would be to use a cheap VM but pause when not in use. When you want to run a build pipeline, unpause it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, we suppose that you could use [VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview) as workaround.

**1**.Create VMSS at [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com)
[image]

**2**.configure vmss agent pool at devops
[image]

**3**.for special start-up configuration, you could [add custom extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-extension-sequencing)
[image]

Comment: I assume that a permanent VM is needed to use Scale set. Is there any other possibility to achieve my requirement?

Comment: @MohanChandran You will be charged only when vmss is scaled in for your queued up pipelines. And according to the document, [Number of agents to keep on standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#:~:text=If%20you%20set%20this%20to%200%2C%20for%20example%20to%20conserve%20cost%20for%20a%20low%20volume%20of%20jobs%2C%20Azure%20Pipelines%20will%20start%20a%20VM%20only%20when%20it%20has%20a%20job), setting to 0 could conserve your cost to a lower bill.